# lombok builder creating issue with hibernate list

Tags: java, hibernate, lombok

I have a class lets say A. It has few non-null parameters. I am using lombok @NonNull and lombok @Builder. From documentation seems like Builder generates the not null check for parameters.

The other side of story is while retrieving A from DB using hibernate list it is throwing exception saying that A is missing no-arg constructor.

I have no idea on this. I have not defined any constructor for A except for @builder and @NonNUll checks for few parameters. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Though it seems like a work around.
Adding @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor and @builder seems good. Hibernate and builder both can happily work toegther with this

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@NoArgsContructor` to your class.

Hibernate uses this constructor and then sets the properties.

When you're using `@Builder`, i think Lombok is generating a constructor that is not the no args one.

Comment: Seems like we can not use both together. It is giving me error on @builder stating that No constructor with (long, string bla bla) is defined. How to get around this?

Comment: add also @AllArgsConstructor